Does modern Judaism view rape victims as less eligible for marriage?
I understand that the Torah doesn’t blame victims of rape and that perhaps the only halachic prohibition for such a victim would be marriage with a kohen. However, reading what the Torah and Talmud say about rape victims, I notice that compensation is entirely for the purpose of ensuring their future livelihood. This comes from the consideration that their marriage opportunities have been tainted, as they are no longer virgins.
I feel conflicted reading what the Torah and Talmud say about these victims. The notion that they have somehow been defiled, dirtied or made less valuable has evoked feelings of contempt in me against a society who could hurt victims like this. The idea that a virtuous woman, who after having her virginity taken against her will, is all of the sudden unsuitable, dirty or undesirable is deeply saddening.
I understand that this is mainly in the context of an ancient society where virginity was highly valued, but this notion is really challenging me emotionally in my study of the Torah, to the point where I now feel compelled to ask for guidance on this matter.

Hi, welcome to Mi Yodeya. This is obviously an evocative question, and might be best left to discussing with your mentor, given how personal it is to you. It also is a bit hard to answer because it doesn't cite any sources, but I still defer to my former recommendation of taking this to a personal setting

See Masechet Sanhedrin 22b for a different take

Just consider for a second that the midrash holds that Osnat was the daughter of Dinah, so she was a child born of rape, yet she married Joseph and two tribes descended from her! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asenath

You're claiming the compensation is because of their marriage prospects; do you have a source for that? Look, in theory the ketubah lists a few less shekels for any non-virgin. Doesn't matter if she was raped, divorced, widowed, had an amicable breakup with a wonderful boyfriend, or escaped a horrible one. As far as sociologically ... it really depends on the community and the individual.

"a society who could hurt victims like this". I have trouble with this presentation. If an attacker had cut off one of her arms, would you have any doubt that the woman will now have a harder time finding a good marriage? Would it ever occur to you to blame "society" for her predicament? I think it would be obvious that the attacker hurt her, not society, and thus the laws would be structured as they are here - to require the attacker to fix the damage he did as much as possible.

@MichoelR thank you for presenting an alternative view, the analogy has allowed me to see it from a different perspective. I admit that this matter is quite sensitive for me, which is why the idea of a woman being less desirable due to something that happened against her will evokes lots of discomfort.

I remember hearing from a frum source that a person's reasons for not considering another person for a spouse are not to be questioned.

@user40118, I think the issue of virginity is one that our society no longer thinks about much. Back in the day, it was taken for granted that in the ideal marriage, the husband and wife were exclusively devoted to one another, and wouldn't have that much to do with other men/women, before or after.  For some (a kohen gadol) that level of exclusivity was required. For others it was the ideal and not always available, but still generally recognized as a good thing.

No.
Back in the day, it was not the girl’s eligibility that changed, but how much she was desired relative to other women. This is still the case in many Middle-Eastern countries.
In the modern West, this is almost never a concern. Men don’t see rape victims as less desirable for marriage than anyone else. (Plus, nobody today would want to marry their rapist).
The Torah and Talmud don’t consider virgins in any way better or “purer” than non-virgins.
